# odbc connect to cluster node error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I recently installed SQL Server Integration Services onto one of the nodes of a single cluster thats running windows 2003 enterprise.  When I attampt to create a system odbc connection to the database on the cluster, i get a connection failed error.

here is the error:

```
Connection failed: 
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 1326
[Mcirosoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB] SQL Serv does not exist or access denied.
```

however if i attempt to connect to the virtual cluster name, it works.

I need to connect to the single node so that SSIS can be recognized through a client application.  Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can connect to SSIS this way, it is not a database server.  You need to use SSMS to connect.  Start SSMS and pick Integration Services from the server type drop down.

You can only use integrated authentication with SSIS to make sure your logged in with an account that has access to SSIS like a user in the sysadmin server role